# How to make a toolbar remain the same Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-toolbar

I am using a toolbar in my android app and the layout looks quite good (see below):
[image]

However, it is not always like this. Sometimes when I load the page it is like this or when I use the dropdown filter or search filter it looks like this:
[image]

I basically want it to return back to the first one if the user is not using the filters. Also, I want the first toolbar to appear when I open the page, as sometimes it shows the toolbar without the titile

This is my code:

```
public class VideoGUI extends AppCompatActivity{
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    Context context;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_gui);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
        ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add("Comedy");
        items.add("Documentary");
        ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, currentPodcastTab.getList());
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: share your xml layout. and the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("your title");
```

This is the usual way to set the title programatically.

else you can set in your manifest like this.

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:label="@string/your_title" />
```

Comment: Also, the drop-down doesnt work either. The bar is intermittent, sometimes it shows the first one (correct) and at other times it shows the second one (incorrect)

Comment: but the layout messes up. it keeps showing the second toolbar as opposed to the first one. I always want the first toolbar to show but for some reason the second one is the one being shown

Answer (score 0):

write a method for your toolbar and  your logic in the method.call the method when you reload the page.

This you can try.

Comment: Sorry but what do I try?